# Set Preselection for ListBox in ASP.Net MVC4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, listbox

In the view, I have

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DoctorList, new { @class = "control-label" })
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.DoctorList, new MultiSelectList((List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.DoctorList, "Value", "Text", ((List<string>)(ViewBag.DoctorsSelected)).ToArray()), new {style="display:block;height:20.0em;", @class = "form-control", Multiple = "multiple"})

    </div>
</div>
```

DoctorList is a list in model, ViewBag.DoctorList is the entire list of doctors, they are something similar to:

```
public static List<SelectListItem> GetDoctorList()
{
    List<SelectListItem> ret = new List<SelectListItem>();

    // load doctors from database
    // for now, fake data
    for (int k = 1; k <= 30; k++)
    {
        string n = "Doctor" + k.ToString();
        ret.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = n, Text = n });
    }
    return ret;
}
```

ViewBag.DoctorsSelected is a List, which is a list of doctor names, something similar to:

```
List<string> doctorsSelected = new List<string>();
doctorsSelected.Add("Doctor1");
doctorsSelected.Add("Doctor5");
```

What I want to do is that preselect the doctors in the listbox. However, it always shows the listbox, but no reselection.

I also tried to use below in GetDoctorList()

```
ret.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = n, Text = n, Select = true });
```

Still no preselection.

Anyone knows how to do it? I'm using MVC4.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the same name for the property your binding to and the `SelectList`. Your model should have a property (say)

```
public IEnumerable<string> SelectedDoctors { get; set; }
```

and the view will be

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedDoctors, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.DoctorList)
```

If `SelectedDoctors` contains values that match the values in the `SelectList`, then those items will be selected when the view is rendered. For example in the controller,

```
model.SelectedDoctors = new List<string> { "Doctor1", "Doctor5" };
return View(model);
```

Note also that `ViewBag.DoctorList` is already `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` so its just pointless extra overhead to create an identical new `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` from it using `new SelectList()` in your view.

**Edit** (in response to OP query as to why the names must be different)

The way the `ListBoxFor()` works is

1. Get the value of the property your binding to from the
   `ViewDataDictionary` (in your case the item in the
   `ViewDataDictionary` is `List<SelectListItem>`).
2. Build a **new** `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` from the `SelectList`
   provided in the second parameter (in order to set the `Selected`
   property of each `SelectListItem` based on the values your binding
   to).
3. Generate the html for each `<option>` element based on the `Value`,
   `Text` and `Selected` properties of each `SelectListItem`.

In your case, as each `SelectListItem` is created, its checks if any values in the property your binding to match the `Value` property of the `SelectList`, but your values are `"System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem"` (they are complex objects so the `.ToString()` value of the object is used) and none of your `SelectListItems` have a value of `"System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem"` (just `"Doctor1`", `"Doctor2"` etc.) so the `Selected` property is `false` and consequently, none of the `<option>` elements have the `selected="selected"` attribute set.

The above is a simplified explanation and if your want to see how it all works, you can [view/download the source code here](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/SelectExtensions.cs).

Comment: Well, you are right, "You cannot use the same name for the property your binding to and the SelectList". But why?

Comment: That will take about a page or 2 to explain in detail :) - but I see if I can add a simplified explanation later (need a break for an hour or 2)

Comment: See update for an explanation as to why having the same names do not work.